# Best way to handle external and internal links angular

Tags: angular

the problem is these links are all dynamic and come from a cms so they could be internal or external,

i have a flag coming from the backend so i know whether it is external or not but i don't really want to add a ngIf and have 2 duplicate elements. i tried adding href and routerLink together but angular doesn't like that so i was thinking of making a custom directive.

```
<a
 [href]="component?.external ? component?.localizedUrlLink : null "
 [routerLink]="!component?.external ? component?.localizedUrlLink : null "
 [title]="component?.media?.altText"
 class="article-link"
>
```

Has anyone faced similar problems and how they overcome this?

Comment: Assuming your template logic gets too complicated, you could always style an input element like a link and handle the redirecting logic in your component, ie redirect user to internal link using `Router` or to an external website.

Comment: "but i don't really want to add a ngIf and have 2 duplicate elements" Only one element will be rendered so I'm not sure why this is a problem.